# Get the color of a pixel on a pyxel retro game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyxel

I am writing a simple shooting game using Pyxel, where an enemy shows up randomly on the screen. I already implemented a strategy to detect if a given shot hit the enemy or not, but a much simpler solution for me would be to check the color of a pixel on the screen under the mouse coordinates. I did not find an API function to do that.

I checked the source code of the Renderer module (https://github.com/kitao/pyxel/blob/master/pyxel/renderer.py) and found a call to the OpenGL lib:

```py
capture_image = gl.glReadPixels(
            0, 0, self._width, self._height, gl.GL_RGB, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
```

I tried to do the same on my script like so:

```py
capture_image = gl.glReadPixels(
            pyxel.mouse_x, pyxel.mouse_y, 1, 1, gl.GL_RGB, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
```

but no matter when I call the gl.glReadPixels(..) I always get the background color.

Is there a way to get the color of a single pixel on the screen on a pyxel script?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
capture_image = gl.glReadPixels(
        pyxel.mouse_x, 
        window_height - pyxel.mouse_y,
        1, 1, gl.GL_RGB, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I change this "window_height - pyxel.mouse_y" for this "pyxel.height - pyxel.mouse_y" to make it run. It didn't work, though. I still get the same result. Also, it doesn't make much sense, this position is not the position I want. I want the pixel under the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

Get the color of the pixel at (`x`, `y`):

```
pget(x, y)
```